# vue-auth redirect path missing param for named routes

Tags: vue.js

In using vue-auth for authorization management, I got an issue in missing param for named routes.

I have path structure like "parent/:param/children" with auth set to true. After directing to Login the redirect back would fail in saying "Missing param for named route.

How can I add the param to the redirection?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can't exactly figure out your problem without some code, but maybe this will help you:

In my router.js, I have this route which takes `:id` as a parameter:

```
{
  path: '/trip/:id',
  name: 'trip-detail',
  component: TripView
}
```

To use this route, I use router-link like this:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'trip-detail', params: { id: post.id }}">
```

So with vue-auth, you can try to pass an object like this to redirect:

```
{
   name: 'name.of.your.route',
   params: { param: your.parameter }
}
```